# Serde deserialising tuple containing varying types

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde

I have some JSON of this format:

```json
[
  123,
  {“some struct”: “is always here”},
  {“optional struct”: ”is not always here”},
  “String1”,
  “String2”
]
```

Note that the second struct is sometimes not present - the array will sometimes contain 4 elements, other times 5. This means that `seq[1]` is always the struct, but `seq[2]` may either be the struct or String1.

I’ve written a custom `Deserialize` using the `SeqAccess` visitor, looking something like this:

```rust
let number: usize = v.next_element()?;
let struct: SomeStruct = v.next_element()?;
let maybe_struct: OtherStruct = v.next_element()?;
// …
```

The problem is that calling `v.next_element()` where the struct is NOT present, it wants to deserialise immediately into `OtherStruct`, which fails because the next element is `String1`. If I call `v.next_element()` again, the visitor has already moved onto the next element, and I’ll get `String2`.

I think I’m looking at this wrong and probably need to write a visitor which receives a method call for each element in the sequence, I’ve not been able to locate any examples or documentation that explains how to do this.

Comment: I think you'd probably need to deserialize the third `next_element` into some sort of intermediate representation - e.g. a `StructOrString` enum. Then you could match on that to determine what to expect for the remaining elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this without using a custom deserializer if you wrap the combinations in an enum and use serde's untagged attribute.

Something like this should work

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde_json::from_str;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Either {
    Four(i32, SomeStruct, String, String),
    Five(i32, SomeStruct, OtherStruct, String, String),
}

pub fn main() {
    let src_with_four = todo!();
    let src_with_five = todo!();
    let f1 = from_str::<Either>(src_with_four);
    let f2 = from_str::<Either>(src_with_five);
    println!("{f1:?}");
    println!("{f2:?}");
}
```

Updated to use tuple variants directly based on @cafce23's comment

[Previous struct version in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dfbfe256c79b72450c89fc368e6742ef)

[@cafce25's example in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e640f84034c78071850651023f7c7a99)

Comment: Yea that's about what I [came up with](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e640f84034c78071850651023f7c7a99) too.

Comment: The tuple variant is probably cleaner, I will update my answer

Comment: This works wonderfully, thanks! It's very close to what I initially attempted, using struct syntax instead of tuples, [which doesn't work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a68e933b81e069daa3c1bc2cfadfd8d7).